# Batch file to detect failure in a log file and then email?

Tags: batch-file, boolean, robocopy, logfile, blat

I don't know if a batchfile is a proper solution to this problem, but I'll describe what I need to do and what I've done so far.

I use a batch file triggering Robocopy and then Blat to send logfiles of a daily file copy task to a target address.  Instead of sending the logfiles daily, regardless of success or failure of the copy, I'd like to ONLY send the logfile if a failure is present in the log.

An example of my existing batch is below.  Please note, I am not a programmer, and only have a rudimentary understanding of scripting.

```
_____
REM - Daily Copy Procedure

@Echo Off

robocopy.exe "C:\TEMP\Source" "C:\TEMP\Destination" *.* /r:1 /w:1 /nfl /ndl /mt /tee /np /log:"robocopy_1.log"

Blat.exe robocopy_1.log -to emyemailaddress -serverSMTP mysmtpserver
_____
```

I'd like to add something between the Robocopy line and the Blat line that will read the logfile and IF it detects a value greater than zero in the FAILED column, THEN proceed to Blat the logfile to my email address, otherwise exit the batch without running Blat.

```
     Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
```

(EDIT)

Okay, I solved my problem with a simple solution.  I was approaching it in probably the most complicated way possible.  Robocopy provides detailed error descriptions in its logfiles whenever something goes awry.  All I had to do was get the bat file to parse the logfile for the word "ERROR" and all is good.  This solution casts a broad net, I'm not looking for any sort of finesse here, so an IF ELSE command did the trick.

```
REM @ECHO OFF

REM Run Robocopy with appropriate arguments.

robocopy.exe "C:\TEMP\Source" "C:\TEMP\Destination" *.* /r:1 /w:1 /nfl /ndl /s /mt /tee /np /log:"robocopy_1.log"

REM Search for errors in the robocopy logfile and email if any are found.

FIND /c "ERROR" C:\TEMP\robocopy_1.log

IF %errorlevel% equ 1 (EXIT) ELSE (goto mailfile)

REM Email the logfile if problems are found otherwise the BAT will exit before this step.

:mailfile 
Blat.exe robocopy_1.log -to myemail -serverSMTP mysmtp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=6" %%i in ('findstr /b "Dirs :" robocopy.log') do set fails=%%i
if %fails%=0 exit
```

looks for a line starting with "Dirs :" in the logfile and store the sixth token in a variable (standard delimters: space, tab, comma, dot; so first token = `Dirs`, second token= `:` etc...)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input.  I assume a /f argument is needed right after for and before "tokens=6"
  
I incorporated your suggestion but am receiving a 
"then was unexpected at this time" error.

Comment: Eduardo: Arggh... JosefZ:  another Arggh....  Thank you both. I shouldn't answer questions too late in the night ^^